# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php, button, if-statement

I am trying to have a button that will check the status and respond according. So i tried using the if else statement to check the status. However its telling me that there is a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF). Wonder if anyone what is causing the syntax error.

```
$list .= "<tr><td>".$userName."</td><td>".$usertype."</td><td>".$email."</td><td>". $address."</td><td>".$postalCode."</td><td>".$status."</td><td>

<form method='post'>"
    . if($status==1){ . 
    "<input type='hidden' name='ban' value='2'>
    <input type='submit' name='banned' value='Ban'>"
    .}else{ .
    "<input type='hidden' name='ban' value='1'>
    <input type='submit' name='uban' value='unBan'>"
    .}. "</td><td>
    <input type='hidden' name='name' value='$userName'>
    <input type='submit' name='remove' value='Remove'> 
    </form>
    </td></tr>";
```

Comment: Control statements cannot be part of expressions. This includes being concatenated with a string.

Comment: You can't put an if statement in the moddle of string concatenation

Comment: you should probably need to study php first.

Comment: You just *not* type `<?php` on top of your code, write HTML as is (with line feeds and tabulation) and temporarily switch to PHP mode to insert dynamic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$list .= "<tr><td>".$userName."</td><td>".$usertype."</td><td>".$email."</td><td>". $address."</td><td>".$postalCode."</td><td>".$status."</td><td>

<form method='post'>"
    . ($status==1 ? 
    "<input type='hidden' name='ban' value='2'>
    <input type='submit' name='banned' value='Ban'>"
    :
    "<input type='hidden' name='ban' value='1'>
    <input type='submit' name='uban' value='unBan'>"
) . "</td><td>
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='$userName'>
<input type='submit' name='remove' value='Remove'> 
</form>
</td></tr>";
```

`if` is not an inline operator, it's a statement so you would have to call it separately.
*EDIT*: if you want to still use `if`, here is the code:

```
$list .= "<tr><td>".$userName."</td><td>".$usertype."</td><td>".$email."</td><td>". $address."</td><td>".$postalCode."</td><td>".$status."</td><td>

<form method='post'>";
    if ($status==1)
      $list .= "<input type='hidden' name='ban' value='2'>
    <input type='submit' name='banned' value='Ban'>";
    else
      $list .= "<input type='hidden' name='ban' value='1'>
    <input type='submit' name='uban' value='unBan'>";
$list .= "</td><td>
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='$userName'>
<input type='submit' name='remove' value='Remove'> 
</form>
</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help it works. I will read up more on it.